# How to use Dired marked files as arguments to arbitrary Emacs Lisp functions?

Tags: dired

Dired lets me mark files and pass their names as arguments to arbitrary shell commands. I would like a way to supply the marked names as arguments to Emacs Lisp functions, either built-in or those I write myself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use function `dired-get-marked-files`.  It gives you a list of the marked file and directory names.  And then just use `funcall` or `apply` to pass them to a function.

(You can also use `w` in Dired to copy the marked names, separated by spaces, to a (single) string on the `kill-ring`, which you can then yank to insert them as a group wherever you want.)